# Can't navigate to URL param using nested routes

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I built a small example of nested routes using the `useRoutes` hook. I don't understand what I am doing different than the [examples](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/concepts#defining-routes).

Here's a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/misty-frost-zrgjs?file=/src/App.tsx).

**I am unable to navigate to the `:customerId` URL param** while in the 'customers' route.

```js
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Link, RouteObject, useRoutes } from "react-router-dom";

const contentRoutes: RouteObject[] = [
  {
    element: <div>Home Page</div>,
    index: true
  },
  {
    element: (
      <div>
        Customers <Link to="microsoft">Microsoft</Link> (this is the link that doesn't work)
      </div>
    ),
    path: "customers",
    children: [
      {
        path: ":customerId",
        element: <div>Customer Microsoft</div>
      }
    ]
  }
];

const Content: React.FC = () => {
  const content = useRoutes(contentRoutes);

  return <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>{content}</div>;
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div className="App">
        <div style={{ display: "flex", gap: "10px", marginBottom: '20px' }}>
          <Link to="/">Home</Link>
          <Link to="customers">Customers</Link>
        </div>
        <Content />
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I haven't completely understood the concept of `Outlet`.

In the examples showing the `Routes` and `Route` React components, they use the `Outlet` component to display children routes.

In my example, I should just change to:

```js
 <div>
    Customers <Link to="microsoft">Microsoft</Link>
    <Outlet /> // HERE, use Outlet to paint children routes.
</div>
```